# Examples of sets with large cardinalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

What are some sets that, by construction, are known to have cardinalities larger than $\mathbb{R}$?

An example of what I'm looking for: the set of topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ has a cardinality of $2^{2^{2^{\aleph_{0}}}}$.

I don't want to involve CH or anything, just sets with beth number cardinalities such as that example.

Comment: Well, if $\mathfrak{a}$ is a cardinality such that $\mathfrak{c}\le\mathfrak{a},$ then we know that $\mathfrak{c}<2^\mathfrak{a},$ by transitivity and Cantor's Diagonalization argument. I'm not sure that this answers your question, though.

Comment: It does not. I'm looking for sets that can be described in a normal way (EG, the set of topologies on $\mathbb{R}$), not sets that are literally just described as the power set of some other set.

Comment: Well the set of subsets of $\mathbb R$ is a natural thing, is it not? It's more interesting (in my opinion) that some things that are naively the same 'type of thing' have different cardinalities. Like the set of Lebesgue measureable subsets of $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $2^c$ whereas the set of Borel measurable sets only have cardinality $c.$ A third order thing like the set of all topologies would be *expected* to have a cardinality of $2^{2^c},$ so I don't see what's notable about that... I'd be more excited if it were smaller.

Comment: (Or maybe the question is really about mathematical concepts that are most naturally phrased in third or higher order logic.)

Comment: Lebesgue measurable sets is a fine example. Just any type of example of any object that has some sort of descriptiom/interest in its own right. Basically, anything other than a set constructed simply with the intent of having a large cardinality (ie, P(P(P(N)))).

Comment: In other words, thinking in terms of beth numbers, if one asks for a set with a cardinality of beth-2, they aren't looking for P(P(N)), because then you're just reporting the definition of beth-2.

Comment: My point is that when we talk about either the lebesgue or topology example, we're talking about sets of sets (of sets) so, naturally things of cardinality $P(P(P...)$ will crop up. If one asks for a set of cardinality beth-2 and is 'isn't looking for' P(P(N)) I think a person should think a bit harder about their question. I agree that P(P(...N)) is a boring example... I'm just saying some subset of P(P(...N)) having that cardinality is boring too (even if it's a nice natural subset), since you'd naively expect that to be the case.

Comment: To be clear, I am certainly looking for sets of cardinality P^n(N), but I am not looking for those sets themselves (including P^n(R)). Basically, I'm looking for sets that would take at least some sort of work to show that their cardinality is P^n(N).

Answer (score 4):

The set of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.
If you consider operations like integration and differentiation to be functions on functions then the set of all these second order functions to be $2^{2^{2^{\aleph_0}}}$. You can of cause run this process of taking powersets without bound.